# Prerequisite to run C# apps that implements ServiceStack.Redis package

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I am not sure if this is the right platform to ask this type of question, am just hoping that someone can enlighten me up on this. I am incorporating Redis in my C# app and was wondering if after publishing the app, must the hosting machine have Redis installed for it to work, I have Redis installed on my machine so the debugging is okay. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis is an out-of-process server datastore which just like an RDBMS your App needs to connect to a hosted instance. It doesn't need to be deployed with your App but an instance needs to be available for your App to connect to.

Comment: Okay I got that and thanks for the helpful response, but isn't it better if it is in the same executing machine as the app? I guess what am saying is where the app is deployed, there must be a redis server deployed too or have I just got it all wrong?

Comment: @lulliezy Think of it like an RDBMS, do you deploy it and run it on the same machine as your App? You can, but it's normally managed as a separate hosted instance. But if you only have 1 App connecting to it, then having it run on the same machine is also an option.